# Following Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I'm struggling to follow this 'supposedly simple' recursive procedure

```
void display(int x, int y) {
   int[] a = {0,1,2,3};
   if(x==y) {
      System.out.print(a[x]+" ");
   }
   else {
   int mid=(x+y)/2;
   display( x, mid);
   display( mid+1, y);
}
```

After the first print statement x=0 and y=0 and mid=0 - this I understand. The next call appears to be the second call display( mid+1, y); now suddenly y=1 - where did this change happen - the print statement is executed and then the value of y=3.Obviously the debugger isn't the best way to follow this - I understand what is happening in the factoral examples and can follow it on pen and paper - is it possible to see whats going on in this example? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "After the first print statement x=0 and y=0" - only if the initial call is `display(0,0)`.

Comment: @Matt - sorry I meant the first time after the if statement is true my initial call would be (0,3).

Answer (score 2):

You should try printing `x`, `y` and `mid` at the *beginning* of your function.

You could also copy-paste, as @Mehrdad suggested, or draw a tree (a binary tree since each call causes exactly 0 or 2 more calls).

**Spoiler:**

```
             (0,[1],3)
            /         \
    (0,[0],1)         (2,[2],3)
   /         \       /         \
(0,0)       (1,1) (2,2)       (3,3)
```

--

I originally wrote something along the lines of this, then thought you might not need it. Now I think you do:

`x` and `y` are parameters to your function. As such, each invocation will have its own, independent `x` and `y`. In this case there will be 7 `x`s and 7 `y`s (check with the tree).

As for the "jump", it turned out to be too hard for me to explain, sorry, but it's, simply: one branch of the tree ending and another beginning. (So when `(1,1)` ends, `(0,[0],1)` also ends and `(0,[1],3)` makes its second call, `(2,[2],3)` - this is the "jump" from 1 to 3.)

Comment: that makes so much more sense now! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's just going through all the elements in order, using a "binary search" sort of algorithm, and printing out each element. I think the result is just all the elements from indices `x` to `y`.

Notice that the word `mid` is a hint: If you're taking the average of two things and getting the middle, then your original variables were probably `start` and `end`, respectively. So try rewriting it:

```
void display(int start, int end)
{
    int[] a = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    if (start == end)
    {
        System.out.print(a[start] + " ");
    }
    else
    {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        display(start, mid);
        display(mid + 1, end);
    }
}
```

and it should look a little more obvious: You divide the array in half, call yourself on each half, and when the length of your half is 1, you print the value at that position.

Comment: yes that is what it does - my problem is I am trying to follow the x,y and mid variables - but due to the recursive nature I dont understand why variable y suddenly jumps from 0 to 1 then 1 to 3 after the if statements.

Comment: @Eternaly Confused: If it helps, try "unfolding" the function -- copy/paste the contents inside where the recursive call happens, so that it looks more obvious.

Comment: @Mehrdad - thanks for trying to help me understand this - im feeling a bit daft and must be missing something obvious.May I ask you am I interpreting this correctly -

Comment: @Eternaly Confused: You're not missing anything *obvious* -- recursion is probably one of the toughest aspects of programming for many new programmers. Let me try to see if I can come up with another way to explain it, and if I do, I'll try to post it.

Comment: @Mehrdad - thanks for trying to help me understand this - im feeling a bit daft and must be missing something obvious.May I ask you am I interpreting this correctly - the first time display is called start=0 and end=1 the next time start=0 and end=0 so the first element is displayed. Here is my problem - the next call is the second display(mid+1,end) why is end equal to 1 now -why isnt it 0 from the last execution? What am i missing here:(

Comment: 2Mehrdad - sorry posted this before seing your last comment - thanks again for trying to help.

Comment: @Mehrdad - Ok I have got it thanks so much - the 'jump' in values is the recursion back up the tree after the base case has been met. Thank you for taking time to help and @aib for the tree that put my brain into gear.This is the first time I used this site and the responses were so quick!